# Better approach of handling failure when accepting array in request body for post api?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have to write a REST Service method that accepts a list of persons as parameter. Here, what would be the best approach to handle the error and pass responses to the client if any person saving get failed?

I am using **Elasticsearch** to store person. Sample code is here

```
@RequestMapping(value="/setTest", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody ModelMap setTest(@RequestBody Person[] persons) {
    for (Person person: persons){
        personService.save(person);
        // Here, what would be the best approaach to handle error and pass reponse to client if any person saving get failed...
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try List instead of array. I tried and I’ll be able to pass array of object from postman.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what kind of error do you want to return?

Assuming you just want to return a generic error:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/setTest", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody ModelMap setTest(@RequestBody Person[] persons) {
    for (Person person: persons){
        try {
            personService.save(person);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle rollback here if needed
            throw new MyCustomException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then `MyCustomException` will be handled in a `ControllerAdvice`. A `@ControllerAdvice` annotated controller can be used to intercept any custom/default `Throwables`. By using this you can pretty much standardize the error handling in your whole application. You just have to decide how should the errors look like and what custom Exception to throw to create that response

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiErrorHandlingAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler({ MyCustomException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInternalServerError(Exception e) {
    Error error = new Error();
    error.setCode(InternalCode.INTERNAL_ERROR.getCode());
    error.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    error.setTimestamp(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));

    logger.error(e);

}
```

### Edit after reading comment

If you want to return partial response (e.g., if some of to return the list of unsuccessful saves).

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/setTest", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody ModelMap setTest(@RequestBody Person[] persons) {
    List<Person> failedToSavePersonList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Person person: persons){
        try {
            personService.save(person);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            failedToSavePersonList.add(person);
        }
    }

    // just put `failedToSavePersonList` into `ModelMap` and return it. You might want to discuss with your API consumer what HTTP status to expect and how to handle this case though.

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @tan-kim-loong , sorry for the confusion, here I was asking about the partial success response with the failures

Comment: @Afroz added my answer in the edit. I didn't factor this out, assuming this is a pretty rare scenario.